# Getting "The base provider of Delta Sharing Catalog system does not exist." error while accessing a Catalog in Databricks

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

[image: Error]

[I followed these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/system-tables/#enable-a-system-schema)
I first disabled all System Schemas using:

```
curl -v -X DELETE -H "Authorization: Bearer <PAT Token>" "https://adb-<xxx>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/unity-catalog/metastores/<metastore-id>/systemschemas/<SCHEMA_NAME>"
```

Then I enabled System Schema through using:

```
curl -v -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer <PAT Token>" "https://adb-<xxx>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/unity-catalog/metastores/<metastore-id>/systemschemas/<SCHEMA_NAME>"
```

After that not able to access catalog itself.
Anyone has any idea of what might have gone wrong?

The error I am getting while accessing the schemas in the catalog.
It shows owner of catalog is "System User".

```
Failed to request /ajax-api/2.1/unity-catalog/schemas?catalog_name=system&include_browse=true: 400 The base provider of Delta Sharing Catalog system does not exist.
```

Comment: Is there a reason you disabled a system schemas first? I assume the command you posted does not "disable all system schemas". It disables one schema. What result did you get? To be clear are you using and actual system schema name instead of `<SCHEMA_NAME>`? and what does this "list available schemas" tell you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/system-tables/#list-available-system-schemas

Comment: 1. I wanted to disable "bliing_schema", but I gave a list of all schemas to the function & ended up disabling all schemas. 
2. Yes I used actual schema name.
3. The "list_schemas" gives the all the available schemas list, but when I try to view those in databricks catalog, I am getting the above error.

Comment: I can't see the error - please post as text rather than image. Silly question: Can you just re enable all schemas and see if it fixes it then start from there?

Comment: Added the error as text. Already enabled all schemas, still not able to access.